# UI not updating Android Databinding + ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

Im trying to do an very simple app using the MVVM android architecture. basically i edit the "EditText" and the text should show on the "TextView". however "TextView" is not getting updated ( its blank text so it dont show)

im using databinding + ViewModel + LiveData

however when a property changes, the UI is not changing

here is the code

```
public class Fragment1ViewModel extends ViewModel {

    MutableLiveData<String> name = new MutableLiveData<String>("test");

    public MutableLiveData<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(MutableLiveData<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable name="viewmodel" type="com.example.viewmodel2practice.Fragment1ViewModel" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Fragment1">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{viewmodel.name}"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.159"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.157" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="468dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="@={viewmodel.name}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.777"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
            
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Fragment1.java

```
package com.example.viewmodel2practice;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.viewmodel2practice.databinding.Fragment1Binding;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link Fragment1#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private Fragment1Binding binding;
    private Fragment1ViewModel state;

    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Fragment1.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Fragment1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = Fragment1Binding.inflate(inflater,container, false);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        state= new ViewModelProvider(this).get(Fragment1ViewModel.class);
        binding.setViewmodel(state);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.getRoot();

    }
}
```

What is the issue ? Thank you

Comment: The MutableLiveData should be made `final`, and the lifecycle should be viewLifecycleOwner

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in how you are manipulating the mutable live data inside the view model. With LiveData you are required to update the value within, not the object perse, so, instead of doing this:

```
public void setName(MutableLiveData<String> name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Do this instead to update the string value:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    // you can use postValue or setValue depending on what you need
    this.name.postValue(name);
}
```